# java: check if an object's attribute exists in HashMap values

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have a HashMap with **key** of type `Double` and my custom object as **value**.
It looks like this:

```
private static Map<Double, Incident> incidentHash = new HashMap<>();
```

The `Incident` object has following attributes: `String date`, `String address`, `String incidentType`.

Now I have a `String date` that I get from the user as input and I want to check if there exists **any** incident in the HashMap with that user inputted date. There can be many Incidents in the HashMap with the given date but as long as there's at least one Incident with the given date, I can do *
*something*.

I can just iterate over all the values in the HashMap and check if a given date exists but I was wondering if there is any better and more efficient way possible without modifying the data structure.

Comment: What is the double that is currently your key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your HashMap, **NO**, there is not another way of doing so **without iterating that HashMap**.

As for changing the structure, you could do as `Map<String, List<Incident>>` that way you would have a `date` as key and a `List` of incidents for that date, given your requirement: `There can be many Incidents in the HashMap with the given date`.

So this would be a `O(1)`

```
 //considering that the key is added when you have at least one incident
 if (yourHash.get("yourDateStringWhatEverTheFormatIs") != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams API (from Java8) as shown in the below code with inline comments:

```
String userInput="10-APR-2017";

Optional<Map.Entry<Double, Incident>> matchedEntry = 
  incidentHash.entrySet().stream().
  //filter with the condition to match
  filter(element -> element.getValue().getDate().equals(userInput)).findAny();

 //if the entry is found, do your logic
 matchedEntry.ifPresent(value -> {
            //do something here
 });
```

If you are looking for something prior to JDK1.8, you can refer the below code:

```
String userInput="10-APR-2017";
Set<Map.Entry<Double, Incident>> entries = incidentHash.entrySet();
Map.Entry<Double, Incident> matchedEntry = null;
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<Double, Incident>> iterator = entries.iterator(); 
                    iterator.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<Double, Incident> temp = iterator.next();
    if(temp.getValue().getDate().equals(userInput)) {
        matchedEntry = temp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a consideration that this is Java 8 only ;)

Comment: His questions was there any other way than to iterate. This is really still searching over the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with your custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). In your Comparator compare the values of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through the map until you find a data that matches. Since you only need to know if any occurrences exist you can simply exit the loop when you find a match instead of iterating the rest of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can only keep a second Hash/TreeMap that matches the attribute to the object, so you can also check this attibute qickly. But you have to curate one such map for each attribute you want to access quickly. This makes it a bit more complex and use more memory, but can be much much faster.

If this is not an option the stream API referenced in other answers is a nice and tidy way to iterate over all objects to search for an attribute.

```
private static Map<Double, Incident> incidentHash = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<String, List<Incident>> incidentsPerDayMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to `iterate` the Map and currently it's the *only* way to get the required value, I would recommend recomment another `Map` that contains `Date` as key and `List<Incident>` as value. It can be a `TreeMap`, e.g.:

```
Map<Date, List<Incident>> incidents = new TreeMap<>();
```

You can `put` the entry in this `Map` whenever an entry is added into the original `Map`, e.g.:

```
Incident incident = ;// incident object
Date date; //Date
incidents.computeIfAbsent(date, t -> new ArrayList<>()).add(incident);
```

Once the user inputs the `Date`, you can get all the incidents belonging to this date just by `incidents.get()`. Although that will give you a `list` and you ***still*** need to iterate over it, it will contain a lot less elements and `get` method in `TreeMap` will guarantee you `log n` complexity as it is sorted. So, your search operation will be much more efficient.